# Excel VBA "This object has no title"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub here, which returns me the `"object has no title"` error. I am at a loss here. I really don't understand this error.

Funny thing is that it worked before without any error messages, but now it only returns the object has not title, even though all charts have titles set to true.

```
Sub embedchart_secondsup()

 Dim totalfailureChart As Chart, iChart As Chart, jChart As Chart

 Dim totalfailureRange As Range, iRange As Range, jRange As Range, destinationSheet As String


destinationSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

 'expected value of Total failure

Set totalfailureRange = Range("'Binomial Sheet'!$A$56:$B$62")
    Set totalfailureChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, Left:=ActiveSheet.Range("J14").Left, Top:=ActiveSheet.Range("J14").Top, Width:=ActiveSheet.Range("J14:O14").Width, Height:=ActiveSheet.Range("J14:O24").Height).Chart
    Set totalfailureChart = totalfailureChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=destinationSheet)

    totalfailureChart.SetSourceData Source:=totalfailureRange
    totalfailureChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    totalfailureChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    totalfailureChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    totalfailureChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Binomial Sheet'!$B$56:$B$62"
    totalfailureChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Binomial Sheet'!$A$56:$A$62"
    totalfailureChart.HasLegend = False
    totalfailureChart.HasTitle = True
    totalfailureChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Total Failure"

'expected value of i % (first supplier) failure

Set iRange = Range("'Binomial Sheet'!$E$56:$F$62")
    Set iChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, Left:=ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Left, Top:=ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Top, Width:=ActiveSheet.Range("F2:K2").Width, Height:=ActiveSheet.Range("F2:K12").Height).Chart
    Set iChart = iChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=destinationSheet)

    iChart.SetSourceData Source:=iRange
    iChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    iChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    iChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    iChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Binomial Sheet'!$F$56:$F$62"
    iChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Binomial Sheet'!$E$56:$E$62"
    iChart.HasLegend = False
    iChart.HasTitle = True
    iChart.ChartTitle.Text = "i % Failure"

'expected value of j % (second supplier) failure

    Set jRange = Range("'Binomial Sheet'!$I$56:$J$62")
    Set jChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, Left:=ActiveSheet.Range("M2").Left, Top:=ActiveSheet.Range("M2").Top, Width:=ActiveSheet.Range("M2:R2").Width, Height:=ActiveSheet.Range("M2:R12").Height).Chart
    Set jChart = jChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=destinationSheet)

    jChart.SetSourceData Source:=iRange
    jChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    jChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    jChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    jChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Binomial Sheet'!$J$56:$J$62"
    jChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Binomial Sheet'!$I$56:$I$62"
    jChart.HasLegend = False
    jChart.HasTitle = True
    jChart.ChartTitle.Text ="j % Failure"
```

End Sub

Edit: I just noticed that the sub can as long as I do not alter anything in the cells (7,4) and (8,4) even though I have no reference to these cells

Comment: Have you stepped thru the debugger to see which line of code is failing?

Comment: The Chart.Title.Text (all of them, if delete one the error appears at the next Chart.Title.Text) is apparently at fault here, but I don't know why...

Comment: try with `totalfailureChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)` just before `.HasTitle = True`

Comment: Actually when it worked before, what did change? The data? The range? Do you have an old workbook where it still works to have something comparable? This is maybe helpful, sounds like the same problem: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e912389-f86c-449b-a359-c033e182bc26/setting-chart-title-through-vba-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt?forum=isvvba]

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this problem as well.  Thanks to KazimierzJawor, I found that using

```
.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
```

before any operations on the title fixed it.

One very strange thing I did find was that the error would occur if the code was executed normally, but when I walked through it in debugger it would never occur... My only guess is that it has to do with timing, and in debugger the display refreshes before trying to set the title.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently come across a similar issue in Excel 2016 (Windows 10).
In my case it seemed that using .SetSourceData wasn't working consistently (possibly due to the timing issue mentioned in Ted Docherty's post).

I had to move to adding in the data series manually using:

```
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
```

Previously (Excel 2016 on Windows 7 and an older machine) .SetSourceData had worked fine but on the new machine I got the "object has no" title error except when stepping through the code in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and and found that for my case the problem was the PROTECTED sheet. So using me.Unprotect mypass before setting the Title everything goes OK...